# How to use TranslateService while externalizing an array of string [Angular]

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I don't know much about externalizing. I was creating a month picker in Angular. In my typesccript file I had an array of months with hard-coded names:

```
arr = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
```

My senior told me to externalize them in a separate json file so that they can be easily modified later if required. Now I'll show you my code.

**monthpicker.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class MonthpickerComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private translate: TranslateService){
    }


    //arr = ['Jan', 'Feb', ... 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    monthArray = []; /* USING A DIFFERENT EMPTY ARRAY INSTEAD*/

    translateCard(): void {
        this.translate
            .get([
                'Months.January',
                'Months.February',
                ...
                'Months.December'
            ])
            .subscribe(translations => {
                this.monthArray.push(translations['Months.January']);
                this.monthArray.push(translations['Months.February']);
                ...
                this.monthArray.push(translations['Months.December']);
            });
            console.log(this.monthArray);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.translateCard();
    }

   /* CODE TO READ MONTH NAMES AND RENDER IN HTML*/
    n = 4;
    matrix: any = Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(this.monthArray.length / this.n) }, (_, i) => i).map(i =>
        this.monthArray.slice(i * this.n, i * this.n + this.n).map(x => ({
            monthName: x,
            isSelected: false
        }))
    );

   ...
}
```

**monthpicker.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let row of matrix" class="my-table">
  <span *ngFor="let x of row">
    <span class="month-name">
      {{ x.monthName }}
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

And here **en-US.json**

```
{
  "Months": {
    "January": "Jan",
    "February": "Feb",
    ...
    "October": "Oct",
    "November": "Nov",
    "December": "Dec"
  }
}
```

This is all the code I have. There is not even a single error or warning on console. In fact `console.log(this.monthArray[])` is also printing all the months correctly. But on the front-end my month-picker panel is absolutely blank. Nothing is coming up. I think my call is asynchronous here:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.translateCard();
}
```

I tried [safely use translate.instant()](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/517) and many other solutions but still it is blank. Please correct me whats wrong with my implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After subscription you need to populate the `matrix` array since `monthArray` will be populated asynchronously. Make the following change:

```
translateCard(): void {
    this.translate
        .get([
            'Months.January',
            'Months.February',
            ...
            'Months.December'
        ])
        .subscribe(translations => {
            this.monthArray.push(translations['Months.January']);
            this.monthArray.push(translations['Months.February']);
            ...
            this.monthArray.push(translations['Months.December']);
            // populate matrix
            this.matrix = Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(this.monthArray.length / 
                this.n) }, (_, i) => i).map(i =>
                    this.monthArray.slice(i * this.n, i * this.n + this.n).map(x => ({
                        monthName: x,
                        isSelected: false
                    }))
               );
        });

}
```

Comment: Oh. Ok. My bad. :-(

Comment: Can you please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59385995/how-to-populate-the-array-for-a-dropdown-where-values-are-externalized-already