# How to populate the array for a dropdown where values are externalized already [Angular]

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I think I haven't understood externalizing concepts very well. I have a simple Dropdown whose options are stored in the corresponding typescript file.

**HTML**

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let source of modeOptions" [value]="source">
    {{ source }}
  </option>
</select>
```

**typescript**

```
modeOptions= ['Calendar year', 'Current quarter', 'Rolling year'];
```

But now I've decided to externalize all the values.

**en-Us.json**

```
{
  "Modes": {
    "CalendarYear": "Calendar year",
    "YearToDate": "Year-to-date",
    "Rolling12Months": "Rolling 12 months",
    "CurrentQuarter": "Current quarter"
  }
}
```

**typescript**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class TimeselectorComponent implements OnInit {

    mode = 'Calendar year';

    public sources = [];
    public modeOptions = [];

    constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}

    translateCard(): void {
      this.translate
        .get([
          'Months.CalendarYear',
          'Months.YearToDate',
          'Months.Rolling12Months',
          'Months.CurrentQuarter'
        ])
        .subscribe(translations => {
          this.sources.push(translations['Months.CalendarYear']);
          this.sources.push(translations['Months.YearToDate']);
          this.sources.push(translations['Months.Rolling12Months']);
          this.sources.push(translations['Months.April']);
          this.sources.push(translations['Months.CurrentQuarter']);

          // PROBLEM IS HERE
          this.modeOptions = Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(this.sources.length) }, (_, i) => i).map(i =>
                    this.modeOptions.map(x => ({

                    }))
                );
          console.log("Modes are: "+this.modeOptions); //OUTPUT: Modes are: ,,,,         
            });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.translateCard();
    }
}
```

The problem is with populating my array of options. That's why my dropdown list is empty. It is not showing any option. I made a similar mistake earlier also but that was some other component not Dropdown. I think I've misunderstood the concept.

Comment: can you post code for TranslateService?

Comment: What do you want to push in modeOptions?

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(this.modeOptions)`?

Comment: @NicholasK. I added that part in the question with ouput. :-)

Comment: can you post `console.log(this.sources)`?

Comment: @Plochie. Oh. Yes. This array has values. `Sources are: Months.CalendarYear,Months.YearToDate,Months.Rolling12Months,,Months.CurrentQuarter`

Comment: Shouldn't `this.modeOptions` print out `['Calendar year', 'Year-to-date', 'Rolling 12 months', 'Current quarter']`? Also, you can remove `[value]="source"` from the `<option>`

Comment: @NicholasK. I just checked. Unfortunately it is empty. Only ,,,, are there.

Comment: And that's why your dropdown is empty. What are you trying to do here `this.modeOptions = Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(this.sources.length) }, (_, i) => i).map(i =>
                    this.modeOptions.map(x => ({

                    }))`?

Comment: Its better if you can provide stackblitz. I think there is lot going on here than you are explaining.

Comment: I was trying to map every single value. But then I removed that also. Still Dropdown is empty. :-(

Comment: If you remove that then you need to make a change in the template as well. Make this change `<option *ngFor="let source of sources" [value]="source">`

Comment: After making this change I'm getting options on my Dropdown but they are `Months.CalendarYear
 Months.YearToDate
 Months.Rolling12Months
 Months.CurrentQuarter`

Comment: Can you try doing this on the template `{{ source | translate}}`

Comment: @NicholasK. Here is stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qbcsnx
It may need some changes here and there as i told you i dont know much about externalizing. Plz check the code. :-)

Comment: @Plochie. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qbcsnx
Please make changes accordingly. I'm sorry i dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were many issues wrong with your current attempt.

1. First, download all necessary dependencies:

   ```
   "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "4.0.0" 
   "@ngx-translate/core": "11.0.1",
   ```
2. Next, setup a loader in the app.module

   ```
   @NgModule({
     imports: [
       ...
       HttpClientModule,
       TranslateModule.forRoot({
         loader: {
           provide: TranslateLoader,
           useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
           deps: [HttpClient]
         }
       })
     ]
   })
   export class AppModule {}
   ```

   define the loader

   ```
   export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
     return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient);
   }
   ```
3. In the app.component.ts decide which `[lang].json` file
   you need to load

   ```
     constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
       translate.setDefaultLang("en");
       translate.use("en");
     }
   ```
4. Now in the component decide which *keys* from the i18n file
   are required.

   ```
     ngOnInit() {
       this.sources = [
         "Modes.CalendarYear",
         "Modes.YearToDate",
         "Modes.Rolling12Months",
         "Modes.CurrentQuarter"
       ];
     }
   ```

   and on the template make use of the `translate` pipe to
   *internationalize* the values.

   ```
   <select [(ngModel)]="mode" name="source">
     <option *ngFor="let source of sources" [value]="source">
       {{ source | translate }} 
     </option>
   </select>
   ```

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/translate-nick-13) of the above steps.

Comment: I think i can learn a lot from this. :-) From here i can take the control.