# Access to a variable from an HTML file, that is not connected to any angular 7 component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having an index.html file that is really simple and contains one component:

```
<html lang="VALUE FROM LANG PROPERTY IN myapp-root">
  <head>...</head>
  <body name="myapp">
    <myapp-root></myapp-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

So I want to set a property in the html tag, and I want to get that value from the myapp-root component. The problem is that my index.html file is connected to any angular component, so I don't know how access a property that is being set in myapp-root.

The code for myapp-root is:

```
@Component({
selector: 'myapp-root',
template: `
    <div>...</div>`
})

export class MyAppComponent implements OnInit {
   static readonly PUBLIC_NAME = 'My Application';
   public lang: String;

   constructor() {
      this.lang = "test";
   }

   ngOnInit(): void {
     ...
   }
}
```

Comment: `So I want to set a property in the html tag` -- Which property?

Comment: to be specific, I want to set lang property in the html tag. The logic for obtaining that value is in myapp-root. Myapp-root has it's own template and logic inside

Comment: We will need to see more code, along with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've updated the question, I hope it's ok now

Comment: This seems like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - are you by any chance trying to do something with internationalization? (since you are trying to do access  `lang`)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to add information about internationalization

Comment: Use [ngx-translate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59385995/how-to-populate-the-array-for-a-dropdown-where-values-are-externalized-already/59390270#59390270) has details how to set it up. Also, [here's](https://stackblitz.com/github/ngx-translate/example) a demo on how you can achieve it.

Comment: The internationalization has been implemented, adding this attribute lang="?", is for screen reader tools, it is nice to have that information, so that the reader is able to read properly

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I've need was by using DOCUMENT from @angular/common

```
  import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';     

  export class MyAppComponent implements OnInit {

    static readonly PUBLIC_NAME = 'My Application';
    public lang: String;

    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {
      this.lang = "test";
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.document.documentElement.lang = this.lang;
    }
}
```